# Cubic curve area charts in Flex, is it possible?

Tags: apache-flex, charts

an example would be the filled cubic curve charts that pchart can create:
http://pchart.sourceforge.net/

is it possible to recreate something like this in flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with Flex's default charts.
[Line Chart Types](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_08.html)

You can also use Flare if you want a free-er alternative.
[Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/)